# How do i get rid of a randomly generated column in a ListView?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listview

so i am adding data to a ListView from a list in a WPF application with this code:

```
 For Each elem As ModemDetails In MDList
        MId = elem.ModemID
        MRole = elem.Role
        MComp = elem.COMPort
        MBrate = elem.BaudRate
        MDbits = elem.DataBits
        MSbits = elem.StopBits
        MPar = elem.Parity
        MFcon = elem.FlowCtrl
        MStat = elem.Status
        lv_modemlist.Items.Add(New With {MId, MRole, MComp, MBrate, MDbits, MSbits, MPar, MFcon, MStat})
Next
```

now the data goes into the list fine and displays ok, but there is a randomly generated column at the end with all of the entered data in it:

[image]

How do i get rid of this as i have another ListView that uses similar code that does not do this??

this is my XML:

```
<ListView x:Name="lv_modemlist" Margin="10,10,100,10" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged_1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="Auto" x:Name="IDCol" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MId}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Role" Width="Auto" x:Name="RoleCol" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MRole}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="COM Port" Width="Auto" x:Name="COMPortCol" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MComp}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Baud Rate" Width="Auto" x:Name="BaudRateCol" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MBrate}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Data Bits" Width="Auto" x:Name="DataBitsCol" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MDbits}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Stop Bits" Width="Auto" x:Name="StopBitsCol" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MSbits}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Parity" Width="Auto" x:Name="ParityCol" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MPar}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Flow Control" Width="Auto" x:Name="FlowControlCol" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MFcon}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Status" Width="Auto" x:Name="StatusCol" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MStat}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn/>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might seem like a silly suggestion, but you seem to have declared 10 `GridViewColumn`s in your `GridView`. Try commenting the last one out:

```
<ListView x:Name="lv_modemlist" Margin="10,10,100,10" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged_1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="Auto" x:Name="IDCol" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MId}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Role" Width="Auto" x:Name="RoleCol" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MRole}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="COM Port" Width="Auto" x:Name="COMPortCol" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MComp}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Baud Rate" Width="Auto" x:Name="BaudRateCol" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MBrate}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Data Bits" Width="Auto" x:Name="DataBitsCol" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MDbits}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Stop Bits" Width="Auto" x:Name="StopBitsCol" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MSbits}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Parity" Width="Auto" x:Name="ParityCol" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MPar}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Flow Control" Width="Auto" x:Name="FlowControlCol" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MFcon}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Status" Width="Auto" x:Name="StatusCol" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MStat}"/>
            <!--  <GridViewColumn/>  Try commenting this one out -->
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```